# Android Firebase - User signed out automatically after changing child data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Thank you for reading. I was working on my MyAccountActivity where users will be able to change their profile picture. What I am doing here is that when the cropping image is done in onActivityResult() method, the program will change the image value of the current user. When the image value is changed,  addValueEventListener in onCreate() method would occur again to read that value and store that image url or string into Picasso like I did in the addValueEventListener. But, the application just signs me out automatically after cropping.

And by printing out mImageUrl, I noticed when I successfully cropped my image, it changed the value, but then a second later it came back to previous picture, then it logged me out.

Can anyone assist me with this? Thank you.

MyProfileActivity.java

```
public class MyProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    /*UI*/
    private Toolbar mMyProfileToolbar;
    private TextView mAge;
    private TextView mGender;
    private TextView mReligion;
    private TextView mSports;
    private TextView mState;
    private TextView mTimeRegistered;
    private TextView mDisplayName;
    private CircleImageView mProfileImage;

    /*Firebase*/
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser;
    private FirebaseUser mUser;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabasePost;
    private StorageReference filepath;
    private DatabaseReference user_db;

    /*Other*/
    private String age;
    private String gender;
    private String religion;
    private String sports;
    private String state;
    private String timeRegistered;
    private String displayName;

    private Uri mImageUri = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_profile);

        /*UI*/
        mMyProfileToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_toolbar);
        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_profile_image);
        mDisplayName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_display_name);
        mAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_age);
        mGender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_gender);
        mReligion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_religion);
        mSports = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_sports);
        mState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_state);
        mTimeRegistered = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.activity_my_profile_time_registered);

        /*Firebase*/
        mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User");
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        /*Function*/
        setSupportActionBar(mMyProfileToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);


        mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                System.out.println("TestUp------------------------------------at addValueEventListener");
                displayName = dataSnapshot.child("displayName").getValue().toString();
                age = dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue().toString();
                gender = dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
                religion = dataSnapshot.child("religion").getValue().toString();
                sports = dataSnapshot.child("sports").getValue().toString();
                state = dataSnapshot.child("state").getValue().toString();
                timeRegistered = dataSnapshot.child("timeRegistered").getValue().toString();

                mImageUri = Uri.parse(dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString());
                System.out.println("TestUp------------------------------------mImageUri: " + mImageUri);

                Picasso.with(MyProfileActivity.this).load(mImageUri).into(mProfileImage);


                mDisplayName.setText(displayName);
                mAge.setText("Age: " + age);
                mGender.setText("Gender: " + gender);
                mReligion.setText("Religion: " + religion);
                mSports.setText("Sports: " + sports);
                mState.setText("State: " + state);
                mTimeRegistered.setText("Time Registered: " + timeRegistered);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });

        mProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                i.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity(mImageUri)
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.OFF)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }
        if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                mImageUri = result.getUri();

                DatabaseReference user_db = mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid());
                user_db.child("image").setValue(mImageUri.toString());

                System.out.println("TestDown------------------------------------user_db: " + user_db);
                System.out.println("TestDown------------------------------------mImageUri: " + mImageUri);  


            }
            else if(resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE)
            {
                System.out.println("Test9------------------------------------");
                Toast.makeText(MyProfileActivity.this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Exception error = result.getError();
                System.out.println("Test10------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Rules for Firebase Real-Time Database

```
{
"rules": {
  // User profiles are only readable/writable by the user who owns it
  ".read": true,
  ".write": true,
  "users": {
    "$UID": {
      ".read": "auth.uid == $UID",
      ".write": "auth.uid == $UID"
    }
  },

  // Posts can be read by anyone but only written by logged-in users.
  "posts": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",

    "$POSTID": {
      // UID must matched logged in user and is fixed once set
      "uid": {
        ".validate": "(data.exists() && data.val() == newData.val()) || newData.val() == auth.uid"
      },

      // User can only update own stars
      "stars": {
        "$UID": {
            ".validate": "auth.uid == $UID"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  // User posts can be read by anyone but only written by the user that owns it,
  // and with a matching UID
  "user-posts": {
    ".read": true,

    "$UID": {
      "$POSTID": {
        ".write": "auth.uid == $UID",
          ".validate": "data.exists() || newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid"
      }
    }
  },


  // Comments can be read by anyone but only written by a logged in user
  "post-comments": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid != null",

    "$POSTID": {
      "$COMMENTID": {
        // UID must matched logged in user and is fixed once set
        "uid": {
            ".validate": "(data.exists() && data.val() == newData.val()) || newData.val() == auth.uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use single value listener for this situation. It does not listen until you call it again.

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Logic for success...
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // Logic for failure...
        }
    });
```

> **Read data once:**
>   In some cases you may want a callback to be called once and then immediately removed, such as when initializing a UI element that you don't expect to change. You can use the addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to simplify this scenario: it triggers once and then does not trigger again.

[original post from firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Comment: when I comment out user_db.child("image").setValue(mImageUri.toString()); , it doesn't sign me out. I think there is problem with user_db.child("image").setValue(mImageUri.toString());

Comment: There is no problem with your setting value code. The problem is your mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid()) has a listener and when you change anything about it, the listener triggers. So, it's about your listener and addListenerForSingleValueEvent should work. Is there any other active listener on mDatabaseUser.child(mUser.getUid())?